# What is the order for watching Lupin III?

Tags: lupin-the-third

I want to watch Lupin III anime. I tried to search it and found in 2018 ( currently airing ) there is **Lupin III part V**. So i wanted to watch in order, like **Lupin III part I**. Checked on *myanimelist* site ( let's put aside first the spin off or movie )

1. [Lupin III part 1 (?)(1971)](https://myanimelist.net/anime/1412/Lupin_III)
2. [Lupin III part 2 (1977)](https://myanimelist.net/anime/1425/Lupin_III__Part_II)
3. [Lupin III part 3 (1980)](https://myanimelist.net/anime/1426/Lupin_III__Part_III)
4. [Lupin III part 4 (?) (2015)](https://myanimelist.net/anime/27947/Lupin_III_2015)
5. [Lupin III part 5 (???) (2018)](https://myanimelist.net/anime/35857/Lupin_III__Part_5)

When i tried to watch the first part, it's long long ago tv series. And there is a gap 35 year until the next sequel from part 3 to part 4 (?) .

How should i watch Lupin in a proper way ? Should i watch the 1971 version first ? Or is there a remake of the series from part 1 to part 3 in early 2000 (Like evangelion and cardcaptor sakura ) ?

Comment: I've looked up several complex anime, and oftentimes "chronological release order" is preferred.  Not always though.

Answer (score 1):

Different to a lot of other anime franchises, almost all stories in Lupin are independent of the others so there is no required viewing order to understand them. All you really need to know is who the characters are.

But if you want to have some hints for watching the tv series, take a look at [this](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/feature/2016-01-22/lupin-the-third-where-to-start-and-what-worth-watching/.97834). And if you are interested in the movies, specials and OVAs, take a look [here](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/feature/2016-01-27/lupin-the-third-the-complete-guide-to-films-tv-specials-and-ovas/.98031).